# Trying to send email through different smtp service while adding attachments

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I'm having an issue when using PEAR with

```
$smtp = Mail::factory ('smtp', $params);
```

to redirect the smtp through a custom email server AND adding an attachment (several in fact), which appears to not be possible.

```
$HeadersCO = array (
                'From' => $From,
                'Return-path' => $From,
                'To' => $Email,
                'Subject' => $Subject2C,
                'Reply-To' => $From,
                'Date' => date("r"),
                'Errors-To' => $Admin_Email,
                'Return-Path' => $Company,
                'X-Mailer' => "PHP v".phpversion(),
                'X-Domain' => $SERVER_NAME,
                'X-Page' => $PHP_SELF,
                'Content-type' => $contentUTF8,
                'MIME-Version' => $mime);

            $mimeCO = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

            $mimeCO->setTXTBody($textcontent);  //Text version
            $mimeCO->setHTMLBody($message);  //HTML version

            $imgNo=0;   
            while ($imgNo < $totalImages) {     
                $imageAtt = $imgarr[$imgNo];
                $mimeCO->addAttachment($imageAtt, 'image/jpg');
                $imgNo++;
            }   

            $bodyCO = $mimeCO->get();
            $hdrsCO = $mimeCO->headers($HeadersCO);

            $mail2C = $smtp->send($email, $hdrsCO, $bodyCO);
```

This will send out an email to the correct email server with embedded images, but no attached images.  The `$mimeCO->addAttachment($imageAtt, 'image/jpg');` appears to not work at all, even if I create just one attachment with a specific file.

I read somewhere that when using PEAR mime & mail you can either redirect your emails to different SMTP service or add attachments, but not both.  Is this correct?  If it is, then that would explain why I'm having an issue with sending attachments using `$smtp->send` in PEAR.

Comment: have you tried something like PHPMailer instead?

Comment: Hi.  Thank you. I have not.  My code was purely PHP, but wanting to redirect through a different mail server brought me to PEAR.  Having a lot of time invested in the current code, I'm just trying to see if there is a solution w/PEAR.  I've heard of Swift Mailer as well as PHPMailer.  Think the later has been around longer?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could look it up I guess. Either one of those should be configurable to allow you to use any mailserver you like.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my dilemma of the limitations of PEAR [sending via an external SMTP server AND adding attachments] by using PHPMailer.

I set PHPMailer to open the external SMTP channel, send up to 4 different emails then close the SMTP session while choosing which emails got attachments, image embeds, different subjects, different bodies, reply-to, from-to and addAddresses.

Overall, my code went down from over 1400 lines to under 800 and I'm quite happy with the flexibility of this code.

Here is the heart of the new PHPMailer code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);     // Passing `true` enables exceptions

$mail->SMTPDebug = false;        //3 Enables SMTP debugging, 0 turns off 
$mail->isSMTP();                 //Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.  
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;     //Keep SMTP alive            
$mail->Host = "smtp.emailserver.com";//Specify external SMTP servers  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
$mail->Username = "username@mail.domain.com";               
$mail->Password = "mypass";                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";       // Enable encryption, 'ssl'                        
$mail->Port = 587;               //Set TCP port to connect to

//Recipients
$mail->addReplyTo('company@mail.domain.com', 'Company Name');
$mail->setFrom('company@mail.domain.com', 'Company Name');  
//Add recipeints
$mail->addAddress($Email, "'".$FirstName." ".$LastName."'");
//CC and BCC
$mail->addBCC('me@mail.domain.com', "WebMaster Backup");
$mail->addCC('company@domain.com', "CC Backup");

//Attachments from array using PHP
$imgNo=0;   
while ($imgNo < $totalImages) { 
    $imageAtt = $imgArray[$imgNo];
    $imageNam = $imgName[$imgNo];
    $mail->addAttachment($imageAtt, $imageNam);
    $imgNo++;
}       

//Content
$mail->Subject = $Subject2C;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $textcontent;
$mail->isHTML(true); //Set email to be sent as HTML, false for Text only

/* =============Sending Customer Email====#1====== */
if($mail->send()) {  


/* ==============Sending Company Email=====#2====== */
$mail->clearReplyTos();
$mail->clearAllRecipients(); // clear all Address/CC/BCC
$mail->clearAttachments(); 
$mail->addReplyTo($Email, "'".$FirstName." ".$LastName."'");
$mail->setFrom($Email, "'".$FirstName." ".$LastName."'");  
$mail->addAddress('company@mail.domain.com', 'Email Sent');
$mail->addBCC('me@mail.domain.com', "WebMaster Backup");
$mail->Subject = $Subject2Company;
$mail->Body    = $MessageEmail;
$mail->AltBody = $textcontent; 
$mail->AltBody = $textcontent;
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->send();

/* ==============Subscribing Email=========#3====== */
$mail->clearAttachments(); 
$mail->clearReplyTos();
$mail->clearAllRecipients();
$mail->clearCCs();
$mail->addReplyTo('company@mail.domain.com', 'Company Name');
$mail->setFrom('company@mail.domain.com', 'Company Name');      
$mail->addAddress($listmail, 'Subscribe List');     
$mail->addBCC('me@mail.domain.com', "WebMaster Backup");        
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $SMessage;
$mail->AltBody = $body;
$mail->isHTML(false); 
$mail->send();

$mail->SmtpClose(); //closing SMTP session
```